# How to move back and forth among many images on a click of back and forward button in android?

Tags: android

I am creating a book app in which i have many text images around 60. I want to move back and forth on click of forward and backward button, just to give changing pages feel where user can read the pages.

Also i am not sure whether to use fragements or a whole activity to show the images.

Answer (score 0):

If the content is static, I do believe the best approach would be to make an array with pointers to each image, then, have an activity that loads the image and make an animation to "swap" pages.

Also, how is the hierarchy you are using? Does the user use the hardware back button to go back pages, or are you using left/right buttons to swap pages.
In the first case, do note that you could create a lot of activities that serve no purpose.

So:

`onCreate()` Start the program, do your styles and etc. then load the image[0]

`onResume()` Update the image, do the transition effect

`onPause()` Save the index of the image array, and the direction the user is going (left/right), then decrement/increment the value, and wait for the onResume, or start this activity again with the `android:launchMode="singleTask"` modifier in that "view book page" Activity

`onDestroy()` Destroy everything you created to free the memory.